# Provider listening to StreamProvider not rebuilding

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I have the following code using riverpod:

```dart
///
/// Data dependencies
///
final authRepositoryProvider = Provider(
  name: 'authRepositoryProvider',
  (ref) {
    return AuthRepositoryImpl(
      authClient: ref.watch(firebaseAuthClientProvider),
    );
  },
);

///
/// Application dependencies
///
final authStateStreamProvider = StreamProvider<User?>(
  name: 'authStateStreamProvider',
  (ref) {
    return ref.watch(authRepositoryProvider).authStateChange;
  },
);

final authCheckerProvider = Provider(
  name: 'authCheckerProvider',
  (ref) {
    var authStateStreamData = ref.watch(authStateStreamProvider);
    authStateStreamData.when(
      data: (User? data) {
        debugPrint('data');
      },
      error: (Object error, StackTrace stackTrace) {
        debugPrint('error');
      },
      loading: () {
        debugPrint('loading');
      },
    );
  },
);
```

The ***authCheckerProvider*** is not getting rebuilt when new data is received by the ***authStateStreamProvider***. Shouldnt it rebuild? ***ref.read(authRepositoryProvider).authStateChange*** returns the Firebase userChanges() stream.

I tried `ref.watch(authStateStreamProvider.stream)` and added a listener to it and the new data is effectively coming through but I don't know why its not working by simply listening to the StreamProvider.

Comment: You appear not to be assigning to state in your .when.  Add that... you need to update your state.  You're also not defining a type for state... you should be using Provider<int> or something.  EDIT: possibly Provider<AsyncValue<bool>> if you want to return an asynValue with a true/false value for authenticated.

Comment: Hi Randal, I just changed the code to: 

```
final authCheckerProvider = Provider(
  name: 'authCheckerProvider',
  (ref) {
    var authStateStreamData = ref.watch(authStateStreamProvider);
    authStateStreamData.maybeWhen(
      data: (User? data) {
        debugPrint('data');
        return data;
      },
      orElse: () {
        return false;
      },
    );
  },
);
```
And it it still not rebuilding